# Proxy setup with Nginx and reverse proxy

Tags: node.js, nginx, proxy, raspberry-pi3

I recently tried to implement a very basic server configuration on my raspberry pi and am actually facing some issues.
I am running a node application on port 8080 and a Nginx server on port 80. To reach my application I had to redirect my connections on port 80 to 8080 by asking Nginx to behave as a reverse proxy. I configured this with my Nginx configuration file as follows :

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name     XX.XX.XX.XX;
    location / {
            proxy_pass         http://XXX.XXX.X.XX:8080/;
    }
}
```

When I try to reach my external router's ip address, everything is fine and I can reach my application without any trouble, whatever the parameters I give to the url. Then I tried to configure a proxy on my browser to allow all my requests to pass through my application. Actually it didn't work and instead of redirecting me to my application, all pages were redirected to Nginx welcome message (that is not supposed to be displayed anymore until I implemented the reverse proxy redirection).

Do you know how I could proceed to configure my proxy in a way to pass all my connections through my application ?

Thank you very much for your help and sorry for my lack of knowledge with servers and networks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a few issues:

1. You are adding a "/" after your port definition (it is already defined by the location tag).
2. You are also referencing your external IP rather then your localhost where the node application is found.

Try this:

> server {
>       listen   80;
>       server_name     XX.XX.XX.XX;
>       location / {
>               proxy_pass         http://localhost:8080;
>       } }

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you very much for taking the time to answer my question. I corrected my configuration file according to your message. It still doesn't actually work and I get the Nginx message instead of my application one. But it looks better to write the rule like this !

Comment: I want to get you there. I feel like I must be understanding something incorrectly. You say that when you hit your external IP you go to your application fine, but when you "tried to configure a proxy on my browser to allow all my requests to pass through my application" it doesn't work. What does that mean, exactly? Could you give me an image example and I'll try to work through the problem with you. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I’m sorry I will try to explain it to you more clearly. Let’s say I want to connect to my node application through my external ip 89.145.202.112. I forwarded the ports on my router to allow external access and redirection to my local rpi adress, then to my application through Nginx. At this point everything is fine, if I type 89.145.202.112 in my browser it renders my app and everything goes fine.

Comment: Maybe I do not really understand how a proxy works but I though if I set 89.145.202.112 as a proxy address it would do something like this : 
req : http://www.domainname.com
req with proxy : 89.145.202.112/http://www.domainname.com
and be the same as typing the ip address directly in my browser but would redirect me to my app for every urls.
As I told you maybe am I totally wrong and I only do not understand how the proxy acts when I set it.

Comment: But when I set the proxy with this address, it renders all pages with nginx welcome message instead of redirecting me to my application as it does when I type it by my own in the address bar without proxy. It looks like my proxy brings me to my rpi but nginx doesn't want to redirect the connection.

Comment: You attached your domain name to your external IP correct? where did you get ur domain name from?

Comment: I do not have any domain name but only use my router's external ip address. Does it matter ?

Comment: I only moved away from home and now I directly access my node application. It might be because of my router and also the issues you highlighted at the very first time I don't know. Maybe fixing my configuration file was the only thing I needed but my router had some issues. Anyway thank you very much for the time you took to help me and answer my questions. I hope one day I can help you the same !

Comment: No problem! Glad to help. Happy coding and good luck with your project =).